# How to update M2M field related data attributes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

[image]I want to update the vote value of each candidate which is related with `m2m` field of specific Constituencies. I have Constituencies update function where user update the Constituencies but i my case i also want to update the candidates vote value which is coming from `object in object.candidates.all`

```py
class Candidates(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    votes = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)

class Constituencies(models.Model):
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField(Candidates)
```

views.py

```py
def constituency_detail(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Constituencies, id=pk)
    form = ConstituenciesForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
```

template.html

```
<h5>{{ object }}</h5>

{% for object in object.candidates.all %}
<h5>{{ object }}</h5>
{{ object.votes }} as input field  
{% endfor %}
```

this is a concept

Comment: Is this what you are looking for (see end of the section for the m2m special case) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset ?

Comment: could you please define this function coz i do't understand how to define with modelformset

Comment: Well in your code it would make more sense to first check if `request.method == 'POST'` and then instantiate your form, validate it, call `.save()` and then `.save_m2m()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Django ORM `update()` function with an `F()` object:

`Candidate.objects.filter(...).update(votes=F('votes') + 1)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update

**Edit:**

Your votes are an Integer field, presumably votes are being cast somehow - a better method would be to have a `Vote` model that tracks other information - you can then use the ORM to count the number of Votes attached to each Candidate

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you have `<model name>.objects.all()`, you get a query set a response.

In your case, if you want to increase the count of each object, you can simply loop over all those objects.

An example would be:

```
# this will return a list of objects which is QuerySet
candidates = Candidates.objects.filter("apply your filter here")

for candidate in candidates:
    candidate.vote += 1
    candidate.save()
```

Comment: Why are you not using [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)?

Comment: because i want to do in template side